# How to keep sensitive perl variables outside the document root

Tags: perl

I have used perl for many years as a way to manipulate MySQL files when producing dynamic websites.  As I learnt my skills back in the days of perl 4 I adopted some practices which are not necessarily the way to go with perl 5.10

One such practice is storing sensitive and static info - such as MySQL usernames and passwords - as global scalar variables in a blah.cfg file which is then placed outside the document root - as I have done for many years.

I then have a line near the top of my perl:

```
require "./../../data/blah.cfg";
```

Whereby I can use the variables to access the database.

My problems started when I add:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

I then cannot have these global variables as they throw errors of course.  So after many hours of research today I seem to be wading through information and finding that "require" should no longer be used an I should have "use" instead.  It seems a baptism of fire with: libraries, packages, modules etc ... and if the module is outside the path I then need to use FindBin to locate it - but not if I am using mod_perl ...

Is there a simple and valid way to store two simple variables and retrieve them in a secure fashion?

Comment: You can use global variables if you declare them with `our`. Both `require` and `use` have their use cases. When using `mod_perl`, set an environment variable to the root of your project and use the `PassEnv` Apache directive to make is visible to your perl code and then `require` your configuration code using that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an actual config file (and something like Config::Any), or if you continued with a Perl module, just do it properly.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package MyConfig;

use Exporter qw( import );

our @EXPORT = qw( %config );

our %config = (
   ...
);

1;
```

Then you can use

```
use MyConfig qw( %config );
... $config{...} ...
```

(Don't use "Config" as a module name; it already exists.)

Comment: Thanks .. after more searching around I think I going to go with your suggestion of a perl module with Exporter.

Comment: So this has put the variables into a different file - which is very useful for me in many ways - but the file is still in the same directory. Do I now place the file in a relative folder and use FindBin to access it?

Comment: `use Cwd qw( realpath ); use File::Basename qw( dirname ); use lib dirname(realpath($0)).'/../private';`

Comment: In the case of mod_perl, you'd want `__FILE__` instead of `$0`. (Works outside of mod_perl too.)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the file path in a perl module you create.  Then, create a getter method on that module to return the file path.

In your main script, "use" that module and call the getter when you need the file path.

Using the module will act similarly to a global variable.  The file path will only be stored in one place (improves maintenance), but it can be accessed anywhere (even other scripts).

I can't remember with Perl, but I think you'll have to "use" your module in any separate scripts that are part of the overall system.

Comment: Using: if you're sure that the module is loaded, and you don't need the "naked" function names in your code (simplifying somewhat), you don't have to use "use". You can just call MyModule::getter_function().

Answer (score 0):

It would be a much better idea to store configuration data in configuration files, not in other scripts. There are quite a few modules that can parse config files for you.

*Edit:*

Why would you have any code inside the document root in the first place? That seems like a bad idea in general, regardless of the whole sensitive config issue.

Comment: This is certainly not a bad idea.  Another approach I've often seen is using a hash as a config file.  No parser is needed and you get built-in syntax checking on your config hash.

Comment: Code in the document root is because of perl scripts in www/cgi/ ... not sure how this can be avoided

Comment: @Upland By not putting scripts under www/.